# Can i join my friend playing rlcraft (Minecraft) from my ps4?

Tags: minecraft-mods

I need to know if I can join my friend playing mods on his computer from my ps4.

Answer (score 1):

## No

If your friend is playing with mods that means he is playing Java Edition and PS4 and Java are not cross-play compatible.